# MKNetworkKit / NSURLConnection etc

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, mknetworkkit

I am building an iOS app that is based on a webserver. I have previous build this app with Titanium and I was sending requests on the server. For example if I want to login I am sending this request:
          `www.thedomain.com/login.cmf?&email=myemail&password=pass`. The server is replying me with a string. Actually what I need is just to send this urls and get the strings.
What it the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple use cases like this, use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode implementing the delegate. When passing credentials around, you should also use (at least) the basic HTTP authentication method over https.

Comment: what do you mean the basic http authentications methods?

Comment: NSURLConnection has "built-in" support for certain authentication methods. There are a few prerequisites in order to make a connection which requires authentication fully automatic. Otherwise, you need to implement the delegate method `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: `. When providing credentials in the URL, you server supports HTTP basic authentication. You may improve your code, so that it obtains the credentials from the key chain for example. That way, you don't need to pass them in the URL, which is also more secure, and possibly "fully automatic".